# Upload a document to solr without using network?

Tags: python, solr

I need to be able to speed up my uploads to a solr index.
In python I am using the following:

```
for f in files:
    cmd = ('curl', '-s', \
        'http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update/json?commit=true', \
        '--data-binary', '@' + f, '-H', 'Content-type:application/json')
    call(cmd)
```

I have a lot of these files that I need to pump into this index, and it is incredibly slow.

I am familiar with the post tool used in the command line:

```
bin/post -c gettingstarted example/films/films.json
```

I considered using a system call, however the docs mention that this command line method contacts the server at localhost:8983. I am assuming I will not be avoiding any network latency with this method, although I have not tried it yet.

Is there a much faster way I can do this in my python script?

Comment: localhost connections should have little to no network latency, since it does not actually hit the network. If things are slow, it's probably because solr is slow.

Comment: Ah thats a good point. I suppose this may just be a bottle neck I have to deal with. I am still going to test the system call to see if there is any difference at all.